# How to preserve portrait mode of iPhone recording in iMovie and Final Cut Pro?

Tags: imovie, video-editing, final-cut-pro

If an iPhone screen recording, which is 1080 x 1920 (portrait size) is edited in iMovie or Final Cut Pro, and resaved as a final video, I noticed the video will be landscape: 1920 x 1080 with black bars at left and right.

It isn't a problem if viewed on a desktop computer, but if viewed in any mobile phone, then, the left and right black bars will "push" the video to be really tiny, about 1/9 of the screen size.

Is there a way to "preserve" the video as portrait: 1080 x 1920, so that there is no black bars, and so the video will be shown on mobile phone as the original 100% screen size, instead of 1/9 of screen?

(iMovie's crop must crop it as landscape size, and Final Cut's crop can do a crop, except when "Share" as file, the file saved is landscape size again.)

I can think of one way which is to use HandBrakeCLI to do a crop, but then can it and how can it be done in iMovie / Final Cut Pro?

Comment: Funny story: some people say Final X is better than 7. Hilarious.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem just last night, editing portrait iPhone X video in iMovie. Here’s how I got around it:

1. In iMovie, when I added my video clips and titles and such to the timeline, I used the ‘Cropping’ edit panel to rotate them all 90° anti-clockwise. It’s weird editing video that’s lying on its side, but I got used to it.

   [image]
2. After exporting from iMovie to a .mov file, I used [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) to transcode it to a smaller .mp4 file (which I usually do anyway). In Handbrake’s ‘Picture’ tab there’s a ‘Rotate’ filter; I used that to rotate it back 90° clockwise.

   [image]

   I’m sure you could do [something similar on the command line with FFMPEG](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24486940#message24486940) too.

Comment: This "picture tab" option has since been deleted

Comment: God damn it Handbrake.

Comment: It is now in Filters

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in QuickTime player (at least on macOS).

1. Open video in QuickTime player
2. In the file menu bar, select `Edit` then
   choose `Rotate Left` or `Rotate Right`
3. `File` > `Export`

**Pro tip:**

If you've used iOS to record your screen, it does so with 2 audio channels - the 1st being mute.  This will cause your video to NOT play audio on services like YouTube.

To get the sound back on the 1st channel, check out [this blog post](https://rynop.com/2018/11/30/ios-recorded-videos-wont-play-sound-on-youtube-howto-fix/).

Comment: This makes a .mov file.  What if I want to keep my .mp4 format?

Answer (score 2):

You can also rotate the video back to portrait in the latest version of QuickTime.

Comment: This *may* be the correct answer, but you really need to back it up with some instructions. The user may not have the *latest version* of Quicktime, whatever that version is. Please be more specific.

Comment: I've added a more complete answer below

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without third party software. I've just had this problem and found the best answer is a mix of Paul's and Max' so kudos to them.

1. Rotate video in iMovie to edit
2. Rotate exported video back in QuickTime Player

**Rotate video in iMovie to edit**

- Import the video into project eg. by drag+drop
- Add the video to the timeline by drag+drop (make sure it is selected)
- Select crop video and rotate left / right with the icon
  [image: Screenshot of iMovie to crop and rotate selected video in timeline]

**Rotate exported video back in QuickTime Player**

- QuickTime Player > Edit > Rotate Left / Right
- Save video under new name

[image: Screenshot of how to rotate .mov in QuickTime Player]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
After some research I found a website that lets you upload your movie (.mov or .mp4 possibly other formats as well) and then you can crop your video to any format/dimensions (and remove black bars) and then save it back to your computer.

This is the site: https://ezgif.com/crop-video

No sign-up, login or any information is required.
(I did notice a slight loss in video-quality, which I could live with in my particular case, but it is something you should be aware of.)

Happy editing!

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to set the resolution (0x0) in the project settings or the timeline settings.